# Call of Duty Advanced Warfare Controller Lag

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

Whenever I play CoD:Advanced Warfare I feel a delay between button presses on my wireless controller and movement on screen. I haven't found this in other Call of Duty games before, or other games period.

Was this an intentional aspect to the game? Do other people have this issue as well? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you using a TV with some type of frame acceleration tech? That can cause input lag between the image and the input. Make sure your rig is set on the gaming setting. I know this tripped me up a bit when I got my new TV.

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind for next time! Not sure if it was, but the lag seemed to go away when we played a different game.

Comment: So you played a different game, went back to CoD, and it was gone?

Comment: Nah, it's only when I play CoD:AW. Other games don't have the lag.

Comment: Bizarre. And you're sure you didn't change any setting on your gaming setup/TV in the process?

Comment: Not as far as I know. It happened at two different friends houses.

Comment: So two completely independent consoles, TVs, etc?

Comment: Yup! One was Xbox 360 CoD:AW and one was Xbox One CoD:AW.

Comment: It has to be a game design choice then. Nothing else it could be.

Answer (score 1):

For wireless controllers: For *call of duty: Advanced Warfare*, it should not 
''Lag''. For me, it works perfectly.

Questions you need to ask yourself:

- Is your battery dying?
- Is your controller off track for one game?

If so, buy a new Xbox controller.

This info may not help, 
and this may help. I'm not sure.